# HTML css/js 'import' path resolution

Tags: html, path

A long time ago I made a multi-sub-domain project which all used the same files.
I hosted the contents on a `cdn.` sub-domain. On all of the other sub-domains I just loaded the css/js files with relative file paths (ex. `/assets/css/style.css`, `/assets/js/script.js`) and I had a `<meta>` or `<link>` tag (iirc) in the `<head>` of the page with an attribute that basically tells the browser to load the files from the domain specified (which in this case is the `cdn.` subdomain) instead of the current domain.

My question is, which was the HTML tag and attribute for this action. I cant seem to find it, and i dont remember what it was called.

Answer (score 1):

```
<base href="https://cdn.example.com">
```

Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Answer (score 0):

The HTML tag I was looking for is [`<base>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)